# How to Google translate API, when I tried isn't providing the correct output

Tags: java, google-translate

I tried with Rest and also used JAR's listed in Maven repo. Which wasn't helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided code that you tried...

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.integrations;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.api.GoogleAPI;
import com.google.api.GoogleAPIException;
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;

public abstract class TestTranslate {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws GoogleAPIException
     * */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // AIzaSyDTxHsEHG0-lVoLLJmG_PwT6L91kXiLAG0

        URL obj = new URL(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=<your api key goes here>&source=en&target=hi&q=how");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(con.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");

                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    System.out.println(response);
                }

                JSONObject org = new JSONObject(writer .toString());
                JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(org.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations").get(0).toString());
                System.out.println(obj1.getString("translatedText"));

        }


    enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Security note, though: you shouldn't put the API key directly in the code. For an example like this, read the input in using System.getConsole().readPassword(); in a real production server, you'd want to retrieve the API key from a database. You should never put keys like that directly in the code, itself.